# Jquery Nested Functions Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, forms, jquery-ui, dom

The purpose of my code is to solve a system of three equations.
What I want to happen is for the "p" selector and the "answer" class to be hidden. When there is a "click" event on an "h1" selector, I want it to show the next element. However, after there is a click event on the class "button" I want the "matrix" class to slide up and then the "answer" class to slide down, revealing the answer to the HTML form's results while hiding or "slideUp"ing the original form and heading.

Originally the "my_code.js" file had no problem hiding the "p" element and slideToggling it when an h1 selector before it was clicked, but once I added the additional code, things went south.

What is happening in my jquery script? Am I targeting ancestors elements incorrectly?

**JQUERY DOCUMENT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p, .answer").hide();


    $("h1").click(function() { 
        $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
    });

    $(".button")click(function() { //after form submission
        $(".matrix").slideUp(300, function(){ //hiding the matrix form
            $(".answer").slideDown(300); //and display the answer
        });
    });

});
```

**HTML DOCUMENT**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
    <title>Kremer's Rule: System of Three Equations</title>

    <script language="JavaScript">
    function testResults (form) {
        function system (x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3, a1, a2, a3){
           this.x1 = x1;
           this.x2 = x2;
           this.x3 = x3;
           this.y1 = y1;
           this.y2 = y2;
           this.y3 = y3;
           this.z1 = z1;
           this.z2 = z2;
           this.z3 = z3;
           this.a1 = a1;
           this.a2 = a2;
           this.a3 = a3;
           this.calcDanswer = function() {
               return (this.x1*((this.y2*this.z3)-(this.z2*this.y3))) - (this.y1*((this.x2*this.z3)-(this.z2*this.x3))) + (this.z1*((this.x2*D.y3)- (this.y2*this.x3)));
           };
           this.calcXanswer = function(){
               return (this.a1*((this.y2*this.z3)-(this.z2*this.y3))) - (this.y1*((this.a2*this.z3)-(this.z2*this.a3))) + (this.z1*((this.a2*this.y3)-(this.y2*this.a3)));
           };
           this.calcYanswer = function(){
               return (this.x1*((this.a2*this.z3)-(this.z2*this.a3))) - (this.a1*((this.x2*this.z3)-(this.z2*this.x3))) + (this.z1*((this.x2*this.a3)-(this.a2*this.x3)));
           };
           this.calcZanswer = function(){
               return (this.x1*((this.y2*this.a3)-(this.a2*this.y3))) - (this.y1*((this.x2*this.a3)-(this.a2*this.x3))) + (this.a1*((this.x2*this.y3)-(this.y2*this.x3)));
           };
        }

        var x1 = form.x1.value;
        var x2 = form.x2.value;
        var x3 = form.x3.value;
        var y1 = form.y1.value;
        var y2 = form.y2.value;
        var y3 = form.y3.value;
        var z1 = form.z1.value;
        var z2 = form.z2.value;
        var z3 = form.z3.value;
        var a1 = form.a1.value;
        var a2 = form.a2.value;
        var a3 = form.a3.value;

        var D = new system(x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3, a1, a2, a3);
        var X = D.calcXanswer()/D.calcDanswer();
        var Y = D.calcYanswer()/D.calcDanswer();
        var Z = D.calcZanswer()/D.calcDanswer();


       // printing to console
       var out = document.getElementById('real-answer');
       out.innerHTML += "<b>The equations are:</b>" + "<br />" +
       D.x1 + "x + " + D.y1 + "y + " + D.z1 +"z = "+D.a1 + "<br />" +
       D.x2 + "x + " + D.y2 + "y + " + D.z2 +"z = "+D.a2 + "<br />" +
       D.x3 + "x + " + D.y3 + "y + " + D.z3 +"z = "+D.a3 + "<br /><br />" +

       "The answer for D is " + D.calcDanswer() + "<br />" +
       "The answer for Dx is " + D.calcXanswer() + "<br />" +
       "The answer for Dy is " + D.calcYanswer() + "<br />" +
       "The answer for Dy is " + D.calcZanswer() + "<br />" +
       "X is " + X + "<br />" +
       "Y is " + Y + "<br />" +
       "Z is " + Z;        
    } 
    </SCRIPT>
</head>

<body>
    <!--DIRECTIONS-->
    <h1><span id="highlight">How Does This Work?</span></h1>
    <p>Type in all the information for your system of three equations.<br />
    When finished hit "Go".</p>

    <!--Form-->
    <p class="matrix">
        <FORM NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">
        <input type="text" name="x1"> x + <input type="text" name="y1"> y + <input type="text" name="z1"> z = <input type="text" name="a1"><br />
        <input type="text" name="x2"> x + <input type="text" name="y2"> y + <input type="text" name="z2"> z = <input type="text" name="a2"><br />
        <input type="text" name="x3"> x + <input type="text" name="y3"> y + <input type="text" name="z3"> z = <input type="text" name="a3"><br />
        <input type="button" class="button" name="button" value="GO" onClick="testResults(this.form)">
        </form>
    </p>

        <div id="answer">
        <h1><span id="highlight">The Answer:</span></h2>
        <div id='real-answer'></div>        
    </div>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="my_code.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: What does "things went south" mean? Can you make a fiddle/demo?

Comment: @helion3 I've never made a fiddle before but this is my sad attempt http://jsfiddle.net/5bhKR/ the jquery code is included in a separate file called "my_code.js", but I wasn't sure how to include that with fiddle

Answer (score 3):

Your Jquery code line #9:

```
$(".button")click(function() {
```

You are missing a "." after the selector:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a number of issues:

- You missed a period in `$(".button")click`, should be `$(".button").click`
- The fiddle had a closing script tag (which aren't needed there, fyi) but you had no closing brackets for the `document.ready` function
- You have an inline `onClick` handler calling a function defined inside the document.ready function. That won't be visible to the html element. You're using jquery already so just use a click handler
- You have several functions wrapped inside each other for the calculator part, that's not needed and will cause some scope problems. You're mixing native js with jquery as well, `document.getElement*` type code when you have the `$` selector available

A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5bhKR/1/) to get you started

Answer (score 0):

Your second `<h1>` (the new one) is closed with `</h2>`. (Might not be the primary problem.)