# Nested JQuery events not working

Tags: html, javascript, jquery

The purpose of my code is to solve a system of three equations.
What I want to happen is for the "p" selector and the "answer" class to be hidden. When there is a "click" event on an "h1" selector, I want it to show the next element. However, after there is a click event on the class "button" I want the "matrix" class to slide up and then the "answer" class to slide down, revealing the answer to the HTML form's results while hiding or "slideUp"ing the original form and heading.

Originally the "my_code.js" file had no problem hiding the "p" element and slideToggling it when an h1 selector before it was clicked, but once I added the additional code, things went south.

What is happening in my jquery script? Am I targeting ancestors elements incorrectly?

**JQUERY DOCUMENT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p, .answer").hide();


    $("h1").click(function() { 
        $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
    });

    $(".button")click(function() { //after form submission
        $(".matrix").slideUp(300, function(){ //hiding the matrix form
            $(".answer").slideDown(300); //and display the answer
        });
    });

});
```

**HTML DOCUMENT**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
    <title>Kremer's Rule: System of Three Equations</title>

    <script language="JavaScript">
    function testResults (form) {
        function system (x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3, a1, a2, a3){
           this.x1 = x1;
           this.x2 = x2;
           this.x3 = x3;
           this.y1 = y1;
           this.y2 = y2;
           this.y3 = y3;
           this.z1 = z1;
           this.z2 = z2;
           this.z3 = z3;
           this.a1 = a1;
           this.a2 = a2;
           this.a3 = a3;
           this.calcDanswer = function() {
               return (this.x1*((this.y2*this.z3)-(this.z2*this.y3))) - (this.y1*((this.x2*this.z3)-(this.z2*this.x3))) + (this.z1*((this.x2*D.y3)- (this.y2*this.x3)));
           };
           this.calcXanswer = function(){
               return (this.a1*((this.y2*this.z3)-(this.z2*this.y3))) - (this.y1*((this.a2*this.z3)-(this.z2*this.a3))) + (this.z1*((this.a2*this.y3)-(this.y2*this.a3)));
           };
           this.calcYanswer = function(){
               return (this.x1*((this.a2*this.z3)-(this.z2*this.a3))) - (this.a1*((this.x2*this.z3)-(this.z2*this.x3))) + (this.z1*((this.x2*this.a3)-(this.a2*this.x3)));
           };
           this.calcZanswer = function(){
               return (this.x1*((this.y2*this.a3)-(this.a2*this.y3))) - (this.y1*((this.x2*this.a3)-(this.a2*this.x3))) + (this.a1*((this.x2*this.y3)-(this.y2*this.x3)));
           };
        }

        var x1 = form.x1.value;
        var x2 = form.x2.value;
        var x3 = form.x3.value;
        var y1 = form.y1.value;
        var y2 = form.y2.value;
        var y3 = form.y3.value;
        var z1 = form.z1.value;
        var z2 = form.z2.value;
        var z3 = form.z3.value;
        var a1 = form.a1.value;
        var a2 = form.a2.value;
        var a3 = form.a3.value;

        var D = new system(x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3, a1, a2, a3);
        var X = D.calcXanswer()/D.calcDanswer();
        var Y = D.calcYanswer()/D.calcDanswer();
        var Z = D.calcZanswer()/D.calcDanswer();


       // printing to console
       var out = document.getElementById('real-answer');
       out.innerHTML += "<b>The equations are:</b>" + "<br />" +
       D.x1 + "x + " + D.y1 + "y + " + D.z1 +"z = "+D.a1 + "<br />" +
       D.x2 + "x + " + D.y2 + "y + " + D.z2 +"z = "+D.a2 + "<br />" +
       D.x3 + "x + " + D.y3 + "y + " + D.z3 +"z = "+D.a3 + "<br /><br />" +

       "The answer for D is " + D.calcDanswer() + "<br />" +
       "The answer for Dx is " + D.calcXanswer() + "<br />" +
       "The answer for Dy is " + D.calcYanswer() + "<br />" +
       "The answer for Dy is " + D.calcZanswer() + "<br />" +
       "X is " + X + "<br />" +
       "Y is " + Y + "<br />" +
       "Z is " + Z;        
    } 
    </SCRIPT>
</head>

<body>
    <!--DIRECTIONS-->
    <h1><span id="highlight">How Does This Work?</span></h1>
    <p>Type in all the information for your system of three equations.<br />
    When finished hit "Go".</p>

    <!--Form-->
    <p class="matrix">
        <FORM NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">
        <input type="text" name="x1"> x + <input type="text" name="y1"> y + <input type="text" name="z1"> z = <input type="text" name="a1"><br />
        <input type="text" name="x2"> x + <input type="text" name="y2"> y + <input type="text" name="z2"> z = <input type="text" name="a2"><br />
        <input type="text" name="x3"> x + <input type="text" name="y3"> y + <input type="text" name="z3"> z = <input type="text" name="a3"><br />
        <input type="button" class="button" name="button" value="GO" onClick="testResults(this.form)">
        </form>
    </p>

        <div id="answer">
        <h1><span id="highlight">The Answer:</span></h2>
        <div id='real-answer'></div>        
    </div>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="my_code.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery Nested Functions Not Working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744684/jquery-nested-functions-not-working)

Comment: You missed a "." $(".button")click should be $(".button").click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error and the answers is a id not a class

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //answer is an id so use id selector
    $("p, #answer").hide();


    $("h1").click(function () {
        $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
    });

    //missing . before click(
    $(".button").click(function () { //after form submission
        $(".matrix").slideUp(300, function () { //hiding the matrix form
            $("#answer").slideDown(300); //and display the answer
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2WVjk/)

Comment: Although I appreciate the help in cleaning up my code, the entire second portion is not working, nor is my "answer"id hiding.

Comment: @rsheeler see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2WVjk/6/ ... it is because `p` cannot contain other block elements

Answer (score 0):

If "p" selector having the "answer" class is not getting hidden, then i can tell u as its a syntax error. Remove that comma after p

> $("p #answer").hide();

Hope this helps you